# Geoapify Geocoder Autocomplete placeSelect on React not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, geolocation

I'm trying to use the autocomplete address component with free API named @geoapify/react-geocoder-autocomplete in React. Already downloaded geoapify/autocomplete and geoapify/react-autocomplete, tried a lot of things but `placeSelect` is not working.

geoapify repo:  https://github.com/geoapify/react-geocoder-autocomplete

My problem is nothing appears on Console, don´t know what to do anymore.

Here's my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
    GeoapifyGeocoderAutocomplete,
    GeoapifyContext
} from "@geoapify/react-geocoder-autocomplete"; 
import "@geoapify/geocoder-autocomplete/styles/round-borders.css";

const API_KEY = "xxx";

export default function Autocomplete() {
    const [info, setInfo] = useState(null);

    function onPlaceSelect(data) {
        setInfo(data);
        console.log(info);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <GeoapifyContext apiKey={API_KEY}>
                <GeoapifyGeocoderAutocomplete
                    placeSelect={onPlaceSelect}
                    placeholder="Ingresá una ciudad"
                    allowNonVerifiedHouseNumber={true}
                    allowNonVerifiedStreet={true}
                />
            </GeoapifyContext>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Tried: uninstall and reinstall, deleting all dependencies and package-lock.json and re installing.
Someone suggested commenting one line in the geoapify node_module but that didn't work either
Also tried to change where the `useState` starts(?) like

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState("hello");
```

to test if the hook was working. It printed "hello", so I think `onPlaceSelect` was never called maybe?
Any help will be much appreciatted

Comment: can you check the react version and @geoapify/react-geocoder-autocomplete version to check the compatibility. ref: https://github.com/geoapify/react-geocoder-autocomplete#compatibility-table:~:text=in%20your%20project.-,Compatibility%20Table,-%40geoapify/react%2Dgeocoder

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to your search and the geodata that gets returned by using the sendGeocoderRequestFunc and sendPlaceDetailsRequestFunc props.

```
function sendGeocoderRequest(value, geocoder) {
  console.log(value); //the search term
  return geocoder.sendGeocoderRequest(value);
    
}

function sendPlaceDetailsRequest(feature, geocoder) {
  console.log(feature); // the result of the search
  return geocoder.sendPlaceDetailsRequest(feature);
}

<GeoapifyContext apiKey="<apikey>">
   <GeoapifyGeocoderAutocomplete
     placeholder="Enter address here"
     sendGeocoderRequestFunc={sendGeocoderRequest}
     sendPlaceDetailsRequestFunc={sendPlaceDetailsRequest}
   />
</GeoapifyContext>
```

See the full example here: https://github.com/geoapify/react-geocoder-autocomplete/blob/master/example/src/App.js

(In the example in the link above, the props I mentioned are used in the last instance of the GeoapifyGeocoderAutocomplete component)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. What helped me was removing React.StrictMode in the root of the folder in the index.js file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35768225)